# How can you have your websites resolution change according to the users screen resolution?

Tags: css, web, resolution

i'm using css to make a webpage and i have been stuck on this problem for a while. i have seen other website resize according to the resolution of someones monitor. i don't know much about css or any other things like it. can anyone tell me how i might accomplish this? my website is
http://ryanlaurence.com/

Comment: See http://simplebits.com/ (resize your window) for a great example of what I believe you're talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's typically done with CSS, and called a [*liquid layout*](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/) or [*fluid layout*](http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/).

There are [a lot of sites](http://www.google.com/search?&q=css+liquid+layout) out there that describe various ways to do it.

Comment: Yeah, looking at his website, your answer is what he's looking for. Not the complex method of the site I linked to.

Comment: Another excellent resource to check out is an article from A List Apart regarding fluid grids: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/


Also check out the article on Smashing Magazine about Responsive Web Design: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/